# Can unattended-upgrades upgrade from Ubuntu 16 to 17 (major upgrade)?

Tags: upgrade, versions, unattended-upgrades

Can unattended-upgrades upgrade from Ubuntu 16 to 17 (major upgrade)?

I assume the current term is "major upgrade" (just as you would go from WordPress 3.x.x to 4.x.x or Drupal 7.x.x to 8.x.x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change you're inquiring about - *upgrade from Ubuntu 16 to 17* - is a release upgrade.

`unattended-upgrades` does not upgrade the release, it install updates within the same release only.